# Cannot access javax.servlet.Filter; class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement OAuth2 AuthorizationServer as described in this [article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/12/oauth2-spring-security-guide#create-an-oauth-20-server) but I keep getting the error below.
For a spring security config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@Order(1)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${user.oauth.user.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${user.oauth.user.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project auth-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/mcs/auth-service/src/main/java/com/example/authservice/config/SecurityConfig.java:[14,1] cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
[ERROR] class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
```

What does it mean and what seems to be wrong?

My pom.xml generated form start.spring.io using the latest M2 release for Spring Boot:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-service</name>
    <description>Authorization service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The article which you have shared asks you to add web dependency which i dont see in your pom.xml file. Add the below dependency which should solve the javax.servlet error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you check within the spring-boot-starter-web pom file you will see a dependency to `javax.servlet-api` - 3.1.0.

Comment: [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.5/jar) is that pom file - it does not contain javax.servlet-api dependency.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue but fixed after adding dependency `spring-boot-starter-web`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: that fixed that weird error message for me 

Answer (score 4):

Look at the version of the servlet api that spring is dependent on then in Gradle include:

```
    compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:X")
```

Where X is the version of servlet-api  spring is dependent on.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you are seeing (cannot access javax.servlet.Filter) suggests that there is a problem with the classpath and that the Servlet API is missing.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Once you have added the Servlet API to your classpath, you should be able to compile your code successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For those using gradle just add and you are good to go

```
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependency hierarchy tree. Does it contain `javax servlet api`. If not, choose a relevant version from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
and add it to your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

While this is a different problem, it has the same error message so if you get here and were trying to get WebFlux to work and you see this error

```
public class PreAuthorizeSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       ^
  class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
```

It's probably that WebFlux does not support your usecase.  I was trying to get `@PreAuthorize(hasPermission(...))` but after much googling found WebFlux doesn't support it and that you should just use your own bean like this instead:

```
@PreAuthorize("@somePermissionEvaluatorBean.hasPermission(authentication, ...")
```